# How do I hide an element with the same markup via jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide

I have two custom dropdown lists that have the same markup. I need to have only one show at a time. Right now, I'm able to open both at the same time. Both should also close when I click off the list.

The same markup for both lists is required, so I can't use unique ID's or additional classes to make this happen.

Here is a link to my fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/dg7Lc/29/

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

-D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider adding a data attribute such as 'active' via jquery when you click on one of them, then hide all those that have that attribute.

Answer (score 0):

`$('.custom-select').eq(0).hide()` will hide the first one.

Use `.show()` instead of `.hide()` to show (obviously) and change the index to `(1)` to get the second one.

Comment: I believe the OP means that opening #2 will close #1.

Comment: Yes - and unless they're unfamiliar with JS completely, they should be able to figure out the rest.

Answer (score 0):

First thought would be if you could wrap a span or div around either or both and use that to get around the "same markup" limitation.  Other than that, though, I'd suggest using order in page - use .next() and .prev() to get between them, and something like

```
$("div.custom-select").get(0)
```

or

```
$("div.custom-select").get(1)
```

to select them from outside.

edit:  if you can run them off of something like an onmouseover, onchange, or whatnot, it's even easier - the one that's changing will be passed into the function as the "this" parameter.  Just hide both, and show this, or show both and hide this.

edit2: similarly, once you have one of them hidden properly - well, that one will be hidden, and respond to the ":hidden" selector.  Use that to distinguish between them (and save the distinction as a jquery variable) before you go showing or hiding anything else

Answer (score 0):

Hide the first:

```
$('.custom-select').first().hide();
```

Hide the second:

```
$('.custom-select').last().hide();
```

And then put these lines of code where needed.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/dg7Lc/31/

Basically, closing the others:

```
$('.custom-select').not(this).find('ul').slideUp('fast');
```

And for closing when clicking outside the box, I used this piece of code but it's a bit dirty:

```
$("body").click(function(e) {
    var should = true;
    for($e = $(e.target); should && $e.length; $e = $e.parent()) {
        should = !$e.is(".custom-select");
    }
    if(should) {
        $('.custom-select').find('ul').slideUp('fast');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind a click to the document, that looks to see if they clicked on the custom-select or the document outside it and hides any open lists as it should:

```
$(document).click(function(ev){
    if(!$(ev.target).is('.custom-select span')){ $('.custom-select').find('ul').slideUp('fast'); }
});
```

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dg7Lc/32/)